# How can I pin the top of the map to the top of the containing div?

Tags: openlayers

If I scroll down, the top of the map appears below the edge of the containing div and the blue background appears.

[image: background leak top]

The same thing happens if I scroll up. The bottom of the map appears above the edge of the containing div. I would like to pin the bottom of the map to the bottom of the containing div.

[image: background leak bottom]

How can I pin the top of the map to the top of the containing div so this blue background does not show up?

```js
const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [120, 15],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSM does not have any coverage above or below 85 degrees north or south.  If you must use OSM in EPSG:4326 set an extent constraint to allow wrapping but not exceed those latitudes:

```js
const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [120, 15],
    zoom: 2,
    extent: [-Infinity, -85, Infinity, 85],
    smoothExtentConstraint: false,
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```