# How can I show just a single world when zoomed out using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I only want a single world to show up. Currently, when fully zoomed out, multiple copies of the world will be displayed. I saw in the documentation this should be controlled by multiWorld which says:

```
if false the view is constrained so only one world is visible, and you cannot pan off the edge. If true the map may show multiple worlds at low zoom levels. Only used if the projection is global. Note that if extent is also provided it is given precedence.
```

It is my understanding that I need the extent to be defined due to the issue described in [How can I pin the top of the map to the top of the containing div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956669/how-can-i-pin-the-top-of-the-map-to-the-top-of-the-containing-div)

I am not sure what is meant by `Only used if the projection is global`, but I assume it would be in my situation.

What do I need to change?

```js
const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [120, 15],
    zoom: 0,
    extent: [-Infinity, -85, Infinity, 85],
    showFullExtent: true,
    multiWorld: false
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the projection work like a normal global projection but not show above or below latitude 85 you could simply reduce the extent of the projection from [-180, -90, 180, 90] to [-180, -85, 180, 85] as long as you do not plan to use it anywhere else with full extent (but it would be better to use a matching source and projection).

```js
ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326').setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);

const osm = new ol.source.OSM();
osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  'EPSG:4326',
   ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90]})
);

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: osm
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [120, 15],
    zoom: 0,
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

For a perfect fit the map div aspect ratio should match that of the extent (world minus the polar regions)

```js
ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326').setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);

const osm = new ol.source.OSM();
osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  'EPSG:4326',
   ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90]})
);

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: osm
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [120, 15],
    zoom: 0,
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  aspect-ratio: 360 / 170;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: When fully zoomed out, there is a weird change in perspective...all of the countries are stretched. Is there a way to avoid that? This would require that the map not fill the containing div and that would be fine.

Comment: Although, I noticed the weird perspective change only happens when the map is small. If the code snippet run on the full page, it does not happen.

Comment: I also do need to be able to show the full extent because I want to avoid needing to scroll up or down when fully zoomed out.

When fully zoomed out, I need to be able to see a single copy of the entire world and be able to scroll the map right or left.

Comment: It  looks like an alignment problem with the reprojected tiles, I have updated to use the original full extent for the grid.

Comment: Is the alignment problem with the tiles themselves? Is this a bug in OpenLayers that should be reported? Or, are things like this normal and one needs to fully understand the tileset to be able to apply such fixes? Also, this is very close to what I need. With your current solution, when I am fully zoomed out, I still need to scroll up or down to see the entire, single world. I understand that using `showFullExtent: true,` prevents the need to scroll up or down, but now the world gets duplicated. How can this be resolved?

Comment: I do not think it is a bug, just the interaction of the aspect ratios.  To fit a single full world the aspect ratio would need to be 360/170.

Comment: How did you come up with that aspect ratio?

Comment: from the extent [-180, -85, 180, 85]

Comment: Understood. If you could incorporate this conversation into your answer, it would be helpful. I will then mark it as answered.